# Bootstrap Modal - Lazy load images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the images inside a Bootstrap modal to lazy load. Right now, when the modal appears, the image does not load, so I thought using $(window).resize(); would fix that but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
 <li class="gift_item ease <?php $cat=get_the_category(); echo $cat[0]->slug;?>">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $target;?>">btn</a>
    <div class="thumb">
        <img class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title();?>" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/holder.png');?>" data-original="<?php echo $image[0];?>" />
        <noscript><img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"/></noscript>
    </div>
    <p class="title"><?php echo textLimit(get_the_title(),20);?></p>
 </li>
 <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $target;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php the_title()?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="main-image">
                    <?php $image=catch_that_image(); if($image):?>
                        <img class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title();?>" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/holder.png');?>" data-original="<?php echo $image;?>" />
                        <noscript><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"/></noscript>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <script>
                        $('#<?php echo $target;?>').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
                            $(window).resize();
                        })
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <?php echo $content;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try to initialize lazyload after the modal is shown.
Add handler to the event "shown.bs.modal".

```
$('#<?php echo $target;?>').on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

Also remove the 'src' attribute from your  tags.

Answer (score 2):

use the container option.

```
$('#<?php echo $target;?>').on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
  $("img.lazy").lazyload({
     container:$("#modal_id")
  });
});
```